# Why render funcion hide img tags?

Tags: theming, 7

I have a simple text that contains  tags but when I try to render the field, the img tags disappear!

```
<?php print render($content['field_with_img_tags']); ?>
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of field are you using ? If it is a `body_format` using a format (i.e.: Filtered HTML, Full HTML) verify the filter settings. Probably `Limit allowed HTML tags` is enabled and the  tag is not part of the allowed tags.

To verify / change settings, it is under `admin/config/content/formats` and click on `configure` link of your used format.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason ! fussy drupal

Answer (score -1):

try

```
print drupal_render($content['field_with_img_tags']);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).